# HTML Tab and slideshow combined

Tags: java, html, tabs, slideshow

I try to create a HTML page which has tab with in each tab a slideshow with 2 slides showing tables. The code looks nearly good, but 2 thing kill me:
Please look on my dev site: http://laurentzotto.familyds.org/joomla/index.php/en-gb/club/team

- When the page is loaded, how can make the 1st slide be opened by default?
- Where on slide 2 did wrong so the table passes beyond the lower border?

Comment: How can I upload an HTML example I generate....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out how to handle this. I had to insert in the tabelement definition the call to the slide routin as "currentSlide()"

`<tabelement><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="tablinks" onclick="openTeam(event, 'Fengig_1_CH_SEN'), currentSlide(1)"..
<tabelement><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="tablinks" onclick="openTeam(event, 'Fengig_2_CH_SEN'), currentSlide(3)"`.

I'm still struggling with the 2nd problem. Maybe someone sees what I miss!